# What is the design rationale behind the resize method of std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Many methods within the template class `vector` take a const reference to `value_type` objects, for instance:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

while `resize` takes its `value_type` parameter by value:

```
void resize (size_type n, value_type val = value_type());
```

As a non-expert C++ programmer I can only think of disadvantages with this choice (for instance if `size_of(value_type)` is big enough stack overflow may occur). What I would like to ask to people with more insight on the language is thus:

**What is the design rationale behind this choice?**

Comment: @user814628 That doesn't sound right to me.  The only time `value_type val = value_type()` might not work is if `value_type` had a copy constructor which took a non-const reference.

Comment: I had never before noticed that there even *was* a second parameter to resize(...)!  I guess I've learned my one thing for the day and can now coast until tomorrow.  :-P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );
```

This function has been **removed** from C++11.

C++11 has [two overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) of `resize()`:

```
void resize( size_type count );
void resize( size_type count, const value_type& value);
```

which is pretty much straightforward to understand. The first one uses default constructed objects of type `value_type` to fill vector when resizing, the second takes a value from which it makes copies when resizing.

Comment: My bad! I was lazy enough to look at the C++11 prototype from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) instead than from the standard draft, and there it is plain wrong!

Comment: @Massimiliano: cplusplus is a bad bad site for C++ tutorials : even C++11 signatures are incorrect there. It is missing `const &`. **Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) over cplusplus.com**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll start using cppreference instead.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a design defect, it has been fixed now.

Quoting from [STL defects 679](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#679)

> The C++98 standard specifies that one member function alone of the containers passes its parameter (T) by value instead of by const reference:
>
> void resize(size_type sz, T c = T());
>
> This fact has been discussed / debated repeatedly over the years, the first time being even before C++98 was ratified. The rationale for passing this parameter by value has been:
>
> So that self referencing statements are guaranteed to work, for example:
>
> ```
>  v.resize(v.size() + 1, v[0]);
> ```
>
> However this rationale is not convincing as the signature for push_back is:
>
> ```
>  void push_back(const T& x);
> ```
>
> And push_back has similar semantics to resize (append). And push_back must also work in the self referencing case:
>
> ```
>  v.push_back(v[0]);  // must work
> ```
>
> The problem with passing T by value is that it can be significantly more expensive than passing by reference. The converse is also true, however when it is true it is usually far less dramatic (e.g. for scalar types).
>
> Even with move semantics available, passing this parameter by value can be expensive. Consider for example vector>:
>
> ```
> std::vector<int> x(1000);
> std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
> ...
> v.resize(v.size()+1, x);
> ```
>
> In the pass-by-value case, x is copied once to the parameter of resize. And then internally, since the code can not know at compile time by how much resize is growing the vector, x is usually copied (not moved) a second time from resize's parameter into its proper place within the vector.
>
> With pass-by-const-reference, the x in the above example need be copied only once. In this case, x has an expensive copy constructor and so any copies that can be saved represents a significant savings.
>
> If we can be efficient for push_back, we should be efficient for resize as well. The resize taking a reference parameter has been coded and shipped in the CodeWarrior library with no reports of problems which I am aware of.
>
> Proposed resolution:
>
> Change 23.3.3 [deque], p2:
>
> ```
> class deque {
>    ...
>    void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```
>
> Change 23.3.3.3 [deque.capacity], p3:
>
> ```
> void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```
>
> Change 23.3.5 [list], p2:
>
> ```
> class list {
>    ...
>    void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```
>
> Change 23.3.5.3 [list.capacity], p3:
>
> ```
>  void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```
>
> Change 23.3.6 [vector], p2:
>
> ```
> class vector {
>    ...
>    void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```
>
> Change 23.3.6.3 [vector.capacity], p11:
>
> ```
> void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
> ```